# how to add tooltips on winform list box items

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, listbox, tooltip

I am using win form's list box control.

I want to add tool tips on list items. I could not find any default such properties.

Please share me , how can i add tool tips on winform list box items ?

Thank You

Answer (score 2):

If you want to do it in a listbox you will need to do it manually. Add a tooltip to the form and update the tooltip based on the mouses postion. An easier way to do this might be to use a DataGridView control like this:

```
    DataGridView1.RowHeadersVisible = False
    DataGridView1.ColumnHeadersVisible = False
    DataGridView1.Columns(0).AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.AllCellsExceptHeader
    Dim mydata As String() = {"Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3", "Item 4", "Item 5", "Item 6"}
    For Each dataitem As String In mydata
        DataGridView1.Rows.Add(dataitem)
    Next
    For Each row As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows
        row.Cells(0).ToolTipText = "ToolTip for " & row.Cells(0).Value
    Next row
```

Answer (score 2):

I able to resolve thorough below ways:

```
'tooltip
Dim toolTip As ToolTip = New ToolTip()
    Private Sub lstReports_MouseMove(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles lstReports.MouseMove
    Dim index As Integer = lstReports.IndexFromPoint(e.Location)
    If (index <> -1 AndAlso index < lstReports.Items.Count) Then
        If (toolTip.GetToolTip(lstReports) <> lstReports.Items(index).ToString()) Then
            toolTip.SetToolTip(lstReports, lstReports.Items(index).ToString())
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

one ref link:

http://dotnetfollower.com/wordpress/2012/01/winforms-show-individual-tooltip-for-each-listbox-item/
Thanks

Comment: Thanks! This works great, but is there any way to change the duration that the tooltip display. I can't read the entire text before it disappears.

Comment: toolTip.AutoPopDelay=7000 ' duration in mS.

  You might also want to set InitialDelay - how fast it shows, and ReshowDelay - how long, after it hides, before it will be shown again,

Answer (score 2):

I thought I'd mention that there is a `ShowItemToolTips` boolean attribute on `ListView`, if you want to use that instead of a `ListBox`. Set that attribute to `true` and then assign the `ToolTipText` values on the `ListView` items.

Answer (score 1):

Sadly, there is no implemented way to show ToolTips on each individual ListBox Item.

You can create your own ListBox control that allows you to do that, like this one:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/457444/Listbox-Control-with-Tooltip-for-Each-Item

Comment: Beat me to posting this link by ab